# Swift DiffableDataSource Snapshot Not Updating

Tags: ios, swift

I am working with DiffableDataSource inside of a collection view for the first time, but I am running into an error while trying to update a view.

So I am working with 2 custom cells. CustomCell1 is a cell that has a Label on the left and a UITextField on the right. CustomCell2 is a cell that has 2 column UIPickerView inside of it. CustomCell2 has a delegate that will let my main view controller know when it has been updated. This is all working fine.

So the problem is coming when I am trying to update the textfield in CustomCell1 with the value selected in the UIPickerView from CustomCell2. As a note, the textfield is being used for text entry in rows of the page. And the picker view is shown when a cell is clicked, and hidden when the cell is clicked again.

So in my delegate to update the cell, I have this code:

```
func updateSelectedCharacter(withCharacter character: String, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(character)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let charItem = self.dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row - 1, section: indexPath.section)), let parentId = charItem.parentId else { return }
            self.updatePlayerData(forPlayerIndex: parentId, character: character)
            var snap = self.dataSource.snapshot()
            snap.reloadItems([charItem])
            self.dataSource.apply(snap)
        }
    }
```

And in my cellForRowAt, I have the following code to update the text field in the character cell (CustomCell1). The gameInfo object is a struct that has information, including the character name I am trying to display, that I will eventually store off into CoreData from the entries in the cells.

```
guard let parentId = info.parentId else { return UICollectionViewListCell() }
let playerData = self.gameInfo.playerData[parentId]
var obj = TextEntryCellInformation(title: rowTitle, rowType: info.rowType)
obj.value = obj.value = playerData?.character
obj.isSelectable = false
return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: textEntryCell, for: indexPath, item: obj)
```

And here is the cell registration for that cell, where TextEntryCellInformation holds the row type, title for the label, and an optional value that can set textfield's text:

```
private func createTextEntryListCellRegistration() -> UICollectionView.CellRegistration<TextEntryCollectionViewCell, TextEntryCellInformation> {
        return UICollectionView.CellRegistration<TextEntryCollectionViewCell, TextEntryCellInformation> { cell, indexPath, data in
            var config = TextEntryContentConfiguration()
            config.title = data.title
            config.tag = data.rowType.rawValue
            config.textChangedDelegate = self
            config.isSelectable = data.isSelectable
            config.customPlaceholder = "required"
            if let val = data.value {
                config.textValue = val
            }
            cell.contentConfiguration = config
        }
    }
```

So now, I think I have explained most of the code. Whenever I select the value in the picker view, the first time it will show the value correctly in the character cell. But if I change the value, the text seems to disappear from the character cell. However, I am getting the correct value from the picker view, verified with the print call at the start of the delegate function. I am also verifying that after I apply in the update delegate function, I am running through the cell registration and the correct value is being assigned to the config.textValue. I am not sure why then, if the config is being data is being set as expected with the correct character name, why the UI is not updating to show that information.

I included what I think is the relevant code and information. However, if more is needed, I will definitely update.

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I found the answer. When setting the configuration on the content view of the textfield custom cell (CustomCell1), I was doing  check to conform to equatable:

```
static func == (lhs: TextEntryContentConfiguration, rhs: TextEntryContentConfiguration) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
```

I needed to be doing:

```
static func == (lhs: TextEntryContentConfiguration, rhs: TextEntryContentConfiguration) -> Bool {
        return lhs.textValue == rhs.textValue
    }
```

This checks the difference to know if I should be updating the config values or not.